# MobaXterm Proxy Corkscrew

Tags: ssh, proxy, http-tunneling

I want to connect with SSH to my Server, at home it isn't a problem. But at work there is a HTTP Proxy between my PC and my Server. I am using MobaXterm for my SSH connection and on there Website https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html i can see the Plugin Corkscrew (Corkscrew allows to tunnel TCP connections through HTTP proxies). So SSH is a TCP based connection, so is it possible to create SSH connection through a HTTP Proxy?

I already installed the Plugin in MobaXterm but I can't find any option to do what i wan't. I googled it but i don't find any example for that with MobaXterm. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `man corkscrew` in your MobaXterm terminal

Answer (score 0):

Download that plugin and put it into Mobaxterm folder

&

vim ~/.ssh/config

Without username/password:

Host *
ProxyCommand /bin/corkscrew "proxy ip / domain" "port" %h %p

With username/password:

Host *
ProxyCommand /bin/corkscrew "proxy ip / domain" "port" %h %p /home/"user name"/.corkscrew-auth

vim .corkscrew-auth:
username:password